# Animating an image inside of an image via Wordpress Divi Theme code module

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using the divi theme for wordpress, I have selected the code module and I am trying to get a picture of a website to scroll when hovered over and to reverse scroll when the hover ends...therefore returning the image back to its original location.  There is an image in front of the website.  Basically this gives the appearance that the user is scrolling down the webpage from a computer. The idea was originally discovered at dividojo.com (Good idea dividojo!) https://www.dividojo.com/website-design/ it is located towards the bottom of the page.

I have the complete code fully functional outside of wordpress with the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>animatingimage</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#insideComputer").hover(function() {
            $("#insideComputer").stop(true).animate({
                marginTop:"-1210px"
                }, 5000);
        },
        function(){
            $("#insideComputer").stop(true).animate({
                marginTop:"0px"
                }, 5000);
        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bigDiv">
    <img id="computer" src="img/computer3.png">
    <div id="imgDiv">
        <img id="insideComputer" src="img/website1.png">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the attached external CSS.

```
#bigDiv {
background-color: #F5F5F5;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
margin: 200px;
}
#imgDiv{
width: 463px;
height: 269px;
position: relative;
top: -430px;
left: 19px;
overflow: hidden;
}
#insideComputer {
width: 100%;
}
```

Like I said, the above functions appropriately.  I am trying to input this into the divi theme.  I have modified the above code to this:

```
<style>
#bigDiv {
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 margin: 200px;
}
#imgDiv{
 width: 463px;
 height: 269px;
 position: relative;
 top: -430px;
 left: 19px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#insideComputer {
width: 100%;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#insideComputer").hover(function() {
 $("#insideComputer").stop(true).animate({
 marginTop:"-1210px"
 }, 5000);
 },
 function(){
 $("#insideComputer").stop(true).animate({
 marginTop:"0px"
 }, 5000);
 });

 });
 </script>
<div id="bigDiv">
 <img id="computer" src="http://localhost/kaiserkreations/wp-
content/uploads/2017/08/computer3.png">
 <div id="imgDiv">
 <img id="insideComputer" src="http://localhost/kaiserkreations/wp-
content/uploads/2017/08/website1.png">
 </div>
 </div>
```

With all of the documentation I have read, I should be able to place this inside of the content section of the divi code module and have it work appropriately.  When I place this chunk into the module, I see the image, and the formatting is appropriate, but the animation is dead.   I do know that Jquery is working correctly, because when i test with an alert function it works fine.

Any ideas where I've gone wrong.  I looked but was unable to find anything on stack overflow similar.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have discovered that the code above does in fact work as posted.  However, it appears that the current version of Jquery is not inherently included in the newest divi theme.  so i simply placed it above the script posted above and it started to function.  I am noticing some errors thrown in the console, however everything is functioning.

***It is also working with placing the jquery embed in the head directly.  I prefer this method more.***